# sort grouped rows itself in oracle Spring/JPA

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa

i have 'Row' table and related 'Cell' table(OneToMany).

i have to select all rows of document. Making left join bring all cells of each row.

```
Row_id    Cell   
1          1A
1          1B
1          1C
1          1D

2          2A
2          2B
2          2C
2          2D
```

Assuming that each cell have column index with relation ,column table also exists. ( A 1st column, B second column and etc)

```
      A   B   C   D
1 - [1A, 1B, 1C, 1D]
2 - [2A, 2B, 2C, 2D]
```

if user have this document and want to sort by A column, then what is best approach in JPA/Oracle? I must order physically row groups by cell in given column index.

For example Desc for first column

```
Row_id    Cell   

2          2A
2          2B
2          2C
2          2D

1          1A
1          1B
1          1C
1          1D
```

Or group by row id  and order by selected cell for given column index.

then i have ordered row id list.but is there a guaranteed way to fetch all rows joined with cells in specified row_id order?

Answer (score 0):

For  now this is best solution for me. First i select column which i want to sort.sort paginate.take row_id and then in main query select all field datas related to this row_ids, resort because  in clause doesn't keep order ,no guarantee .

```
SELECT doc_row.id ,
  doc_row.delimiter_delimiter_id,
  user_username ,
  doc_row.isdraft,
  LISTAGG(NVL(value, ''), ',') WITHIN GROUP (
ORDER BY col_index) AS cells
FROM data
LEFT JOIN field
ON field.field_id = field_field_id
LEFT JOIN doc_row
ON doc_row.id = data.row_id
WHERE row_id IN
  (SELECT q
  FROM
    (SELECT my_query.row_id q,
      rownum rn
    FROM
      (SELECT row_id
      FROM data
      LEFT JOIN doc_row
      ON data.row_id                = doc_row.id
      WHERE delimiter_delimiter_id IN (1)
      AND field_field_id            = (3)
      ORDER BY to_date(value,'DD/MM/YYYY')
      ) my_query
    WHERE rownum <= (2000)
    )
  WHERE rn >= (0)
  )
GROUP BY doc_row.id ,
  delimiter_delimiter_id,
  user_username,
  isdraft
ORDER BY to_date(REGEXP_SUBSTR(cells, '[^,]+',1,(3)),'DD/MM/YYYY')
```